# May I assume this open set is connected 2?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $W$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq1$). To prove that some function is constant on   the interior of the closure of $W$, may I assume that the closure of $W$ is connected?

Comment: I don't see how that would suffice. How do you propose to prove that the result for connected $\overline W$ implies the general result?

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W=(1,2)\cup(3,4)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$ whose closure $\overline{W}=[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ is not connected. On the other hand, it's unlikely that what you're trying to prove (unfortunately, you didn't provide us with the specific context) is true in such a case, as the two components are completely disjoint. Any function defined on such a set would be effectively a piecewise function consisting of two "separate" functions defined on the two components. (Again, without knowing the context, I'm guessing in the dark here.)

So you should look deeper into the context of your problem. Either there are additional conditions that guarantee that the closure is connected (maybe $W$ was connected to begin with?), or maybe it's good enough for you to show that the function is constant in the interior of any connected component, or maybe there's something else going on…

Comment: I made an assumption that intuitively seems correct: If $(C_{k})$ are the connected components of $W$, by taking the closure of $W$, the closure of some of the connected components will form closed connected sets, and we can write 
$$\overline{W} =\bigcup_{k}W_{k},$$
where $(W_{k})$ are disjoint closed sets. This way, the interior of $\overline{W}$ will equal the union of the interiors of $ W_{k}$. If this assumption is correct, I can assume $W$ connected.  Is this assumption true?